# Feedback wanted: link GitHub projects to SO Careers profile

Tags: discussion, jobs, feedback, github

We just deployed the ability to add GitHub projects to your Stack Overflow Careers profile.  Before announcing it to the world, we thought we'd see what you all think.

**If you have a GitHub account and would like to test it out but haven't been invited to Careers yet, we'll invite the first few dozen people who email careers@stackoverflow.com with a link to their GitHub account.**

Some screenshots:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: plans to add bitbucket, codeplex, sourceforge, etc?

Comment: @qntmfred: in due time.  We want to make sure we're doing it right first, and looking for as much feedback as possible about the github integration for now.

Comment: What, if any, are the advantages of having site-specific links like this? Would it be better to have a generic section for "open-source projects I've worked on" instead?

Comment: @Jon: I think the idea is that there is an actual connection between the user's SO account and their github account. In other words, the person reading your profile knows that it's your work, maybe?

Comment: @Gabe but it isn't necessarily. You could conceivably clone the linux kernel into a github account and most of it would definitely not be your work. But it does show that a) you have a reasonable idea of how to use version control in theory and b) recruiters can look at commits, assuming your name is next to them and assuming they actually bother with that level of recruitment. Of the past two interviews I've attended, BOTH have commented to me on my stackoverflow profile... so why not give them github too? +1.

Comment: I'm curious if that's a real project or a made up one. What's wrong with output caching in MVC3 ? :P

Comment: I've found a [bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87529/error-on-careers-showing-the-display-more-link-when-there-are-more-than-3-githu) having to do with showing the "display more" link.   I thought about just adding it as a comment here, then I thought it was a big enough deal to warrant it's own question, so I'm doing both.

Should be an easy fix, just thought it should get reported.

Comment: @Tommy we see the bug, we'll get it fixed

Comment: Thank you! and thanks for the quick feedback! Stack Overflow rocks.  While I'm here, just wanted to say thanks for what you all have done for the development community.

Comment: @David: Please tell me you haven't forgotten about Launchpad... :)

Comment: @George We're trying to work with Launchpad to get an API that we can use.  In the meantime you can use the "Other" option

Answer (score 8):

Obligatory request for [Google Code](http://code.google.com/hosting/) (Google Project Hosting) support.

Comment: Looks like this has been done now.

Comment: Thanks to SO for getting this done so quickly (even if it is scrape-tacular).  Note that a URL in the format http://code.google.com/u/user@domain.com/ will not work.  When you visit your page (formatted like that) while logged in, your email at top left will be a link to a URL with the required code.

Answer (score 8):

Obligatory request for [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/) (Microsoft Open Source Project Hosting) support.

Comment: Yes please, I have all of my projects at CodePlex and would definitely like to link to them.

Comment: +1 almost all my open source work is at CodePlex

Answer (score 7):

Obligatory request for [Launchpad support](https://launchpad.net/).

---

*Note: Launchpad API info is [here](https://help.launchpad.net/API).*

Comment: And here's to hoping it will recognize not just projects owned by me, but also those hosted on launchpad that I contribute to (eg Ubuntu).

Comment: @Scott: What it *should* do is recognize *branches* owned by you.

Comment: There is still a lot of non-branch Launchpad code activity - Ubuntu uploads, for instance - but treating Launchpad:bzr like Github:git is probably reasonable.

Answer (score 6):

https://bitbucket.org/

Oh, wait. That would be the competition of Kiln. It'd still make a good candidate, though.

Comment: Not until Kiln is free.

Comment: Looks like bitbucket.org, Google Code, and SourceForge are now supported. Needs Codeplex.com support next

Answer (score 3):

This rocks!

I like the idea of using SO's tagging system on repos. Is this exposed to recruiters? I.e. look for all the candidates who have a *code repository listed* with say a tag like [boost](/questions/tagged/boost) i.e. *code I can actually look at?*.

Comment: They can't filter by it, but it's included with all other tags (i.e. if they search [boost] they'll see people who have repos with that tag, and people who answered questions with that tag, and people who list it under "favorites", etc)

Answer (score 2):

At the moment only github is supported, but many people (including me) use [codaset](http://codaset.com/) instead. Are you planning to add integration with codaset? [savannah](http://savannah.gnu.org) is also a good place where many free software projects are hosted.

Answer (score 1):

Good stuff.  One minor problem is that it lists the start date for the project as the date that the GitHub repository was created.  Perhaps this is a limitation of the GitHub API but it would be better to use my earliest commit date from the repository.  Most of my projects on GitHub existed for a few years before I moved them there.

**Edit:** <s>One other thing, it doesn't seem to be possible to remove a project from your profile once you've added it.</s> (Never mind, I found it, it's in a different place to the "add" functionality).

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to see support for projects under an organisation I contribute to. The majority of my work occurs under these. I'm not sure whether GitHub supports this though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd love to be able to link to public kiln repositories.