# Why doesn't careers.stackoverflow.com have link to codeplex?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I notice that I can link to github, but not codeplex.  Given the large number of .net developers on this site, I think a link to codeplex should also be available.

Comment: see comments on original announcement: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85197/feedback-wanted-link-github-projects-to-so-careers-profile. We'll add others in due time.

Comment: On the same subject, I'd also like to see a link to code.google.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give it time. Github is still experimental. I'm sure that if it works out, other sites will be added.

Answer (score 8):

We want to do Codeplex, but I don't see an API for them. We may resort to scraping.

Update: they created an API and this has been implemented.