# Bitbucket/Codeplex badge on careers cv

Tags: feature-request, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Feedback wanted: link GitHub projects to SO Careers profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85197/feedback-wanted-link-github-projects-to-so-careers-profile)

I see that Github link was just added but I'm wondering if anyone on the Careers team considered implementing a link to Mercurial repositories, like Bitbucket or Codeplex?

It would be nice not to have to move all check-ins to Github just to have it on the CV.

Comment: See the comments on this question - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85197/feedback-wanted-link-github-projects-to-so-careers-profile - it's already planned to have others.