# Error on Careers showing the "display more" link when there are more than 3 github projects listed

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, github

I thought about adding this as a comment to [Feedback wanted: link GitHub projects to SO Careers profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85197/feedback-wanted-link-github-projects-to-so-careers-profile) but since this is a UI bug, I thought it was a big enough deal for its own question.

When a user has more than 3 github profiles listed on their careers page the link for "display more" renders the full anchor tag on the client.

Please see [My CV on Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/thinrichscv)

A potential employer is going to look at my page today... so it's a little embarrassing.  Especially since I was going to evangelize careers to their HR department.

Comment: we'll get it fixed ASAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Tommy, sorry about that. This has been resolved.

Comment: You guys move quick!  Agility at work! (pun intended)  Thanks